# Has the -1 rep for downvoting a question or answer gone?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

I haven't noticed a loss in rep for doing that recently; also on Gaming.

Comment: gone for questions, but still there for answers. See blog post link Maik posted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes its gone: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/

Comment: It's *half* -gone: `Downvotes on *questions* no longer cost the casting user 1 reputation, so they are effectively “free”`. Answers weren't mentioned as changing, so I presume they didn't (haven't tried it yet).

Answer (score 1):

I've always thought the loss 1 is a good thing. So, people dont just go ahead and click the down button just because, s/he feels its not good at their first glance.

Comment: Perhaps people should work on writing questions that are good at first glance.

Comment: Not every people in this earth has born with English as their first language. Its pretty obvious to face some difficulties, to find the right word and pattern to express what they want to. A lot Japanese game developers can't even speak English well. Does it mean it will be awkward for them to participate in the conversation. And there is always a comment part, if you don't understand, simply raise an issue. I have seen a lot people doing that.

Comment: Outside of one user, I don't think we've seen a problem with otherwise good questions rejected because they contain poor grammar (although I admit I'm not the best person to judge that). On the other hand I think we have a problem with genuinely bad questions, mostly from native English writers, not getting downvoted enough.

Comment: For example http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/14444/game-sound-effects-availability is fine grammar, but the question is half duplicate and half non-question, and yet it's made it to +3, and your answer at +3. I downvoted your answer because it belongs split up and at the question Tetrad linked, and not because of any grammar problems.

Comment: I didn't read [the blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/). Its great! I agree its ok. But, sometimes I face this situation. Once I asked *64bit lib with 32bit OS compatibility*. People just went on download voting, while commenting "I dont understand", but, after that few(not me) explained what I was talking about. Then those "dont understand" comments were deleted and question was upvoted again.

Comment: @joe-wreschnig I answered the question 14 hours ago, and Tetrad linked 5 hours ago. I don't understand what you mean by "belongs split up".